# scrollHeight value for a div containing images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Here is a div, containing images, with max-height: 300px. Whenever a scrollbar is needed (this is the case here), I want to add a second div (the gray one) next to the first. I use scrollHeight to test the presence of a scrollbar.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="pictures">
        <img src="test1.jpg" /> <img src="test2.jpg" /> <img src="test3.jpg" /> <img src="test4.jpg" />
        <img src="test5.jpg" /> <img src="test6.jpg" /> <img src="test7.jpg" /> <img src="test8.jpg" />
        <img src="test9.jpg" /> <img src="test10.jpg" /> <img src="test11.jpg" /> <img src="test12.jpg" />
        <img src="test13.jpg" /> <img src="test14.jpg" /> <img src="test15.jpg" /> <img src="test16.jpg" />
        <img src="test17.jpg" /> <img src="test18.jpg" /> <img src="test19.jpg" /> <img src="test20.jpg" />
        <img src="test21.jpg" /> <img src="test22.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="scroll"></div>
</div>
```

Some CSS:

```
div.container {
        width: 410px;
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    div.container div.pictures {
        float: left;
        width: 390px;
    }
    div.container div.scroll {
        display: none;
        float: left;
        width: 30px;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
```

And the JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".scroll").each(function() {
        var iParentHeight = $(this).parent()[0].scrollHeight;
        if (iParentHeight > $(this).parent().css("max-height").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '')) {
            var iWidth = $(this).parent().width()+$(this).width();
            $(this).parent().css("width", iWidth);
            $(this).show();
            $(this).height(iParentHeight);
        }
    });
});
```

On Firefox it's working. On Chrome and Safari though, there is some issue: sometimes (actually, most of the time for Safari) the gray dive does not appear when it should.

I made some tests: without images, with X time the same image and with X different images. The issue is only appearing when there is X different images (maybe some loading time problem?).

In fact, the output of scrollHeight is not always the same on Chrome and Safari. For FF, I always get the same result.

Any idea would be appreciated!

Edit: forgot the link with an example: http://toolboxebz.free.fr/test_scroll/test.html

Comment: i guess images should be fully loaded before calling script, DOM ready handler doesn't wait for that. Window onload will do or better check for specific images to be fully loaded using corresponding onload events

Comment: window onload is doing fine, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should wrap your js function in a `document.ready` or utilize something like [imageloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded), as you said the behaviour is not deterministic, that's due to the fact that when your function runs, images could be not already fully loaded in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. document.ready is already there though, in it's shorthand version $. But the comment from A. Wolff solved my problem anyway!